# Any way to remove these useless faces all at once?

Tags: modeling

[image: Modeled a mesh grille but forgot to clean up these and now I don't want to remodel it all over again]

Modeled a mesh grille but forgot to clean up these and now I don't want to remodel it all over again

Comment: Hello and welcome. you could select one set of perpendicular sides and press `F` *> Intersect (Knife)*. This will split the faces of the planes perpendicular to your selection and then you can select and delete them.

Comment: How are we supposed to guess what the topology of the mesh is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I get it you do want to remove "interior faces" and they're repetitive and you don't want to do it one by one, so here is a replicate of your issue down here in this animated image.

1. Hit <kbd>TAB</kbd> key on your keyboard to get into *Edit Mode*
2. From the select menu choose "Select All by Trait" then choose "Interior Faces"
3. Press <kbd>X</kbd> and delete those faces

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Select object, press <kbd>3</kbd>, select faces, press  <kbd>X</kbd> and choose *Delete > Faces*

Comment: OH, use "shift + G" to select all similar objects/faces/vertex etc etc !

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit? The way this answer is currently worded, I'm afraid it doesn't really help anyone. Thank you for your understanding.